# drawing on an externally loaded svg graphic in D3

Tags: animation, svg, d3.js

I have loaded an external graphic from an svg file and I want to experiment drawing on it but cannot figure out how. my simple d3 code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     d3.xml("brussels.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
     document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
       });

     svg.append("circle")
     .style("stroke", "gray")
     .style("fill", "white")
     .attr("r", 40)
     .attr("cx", 50)
     .attr("cy", 50)
     .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
     .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am sure it is something simple but I am not sure how to create the actual circle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function:

```js
 d3.xml("brussels.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
   document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
 });
```

executes *asynchronously*. Hence, the code following it is executed before the callback is executed. The second problem is that you need to define the `svg` variable before you can operate on it.

Something like the following should work:

```js
 d3.xml("brussels.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
   document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);

   var svg = d3.select('svg');

   svg.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});
 });
```

Comment: Thank-you, makes sense. Is there an easy way to read in a file like a csv and draw the circles. Is this a big change from this code?

Comment: No, it is not a big change. Have a look at [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) and the related examples.

Comment: Did this adequately answer your question?